# PayPal Credit/Debit Card details to save in Db

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal smart buttons for Payment processing, where users can pay using PayPal account or Credit/debit card.

I want to save the last four digits of Credit/Debit card entered by the user for payment in the database.

How can I get that Credit/Debit card number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get that information. You also cannot get information on whether or not a credit/debit card was used to pay -- some other payment method may have been used to pay. A customer's billing information is kept private to their PayPal account. All you know is that you received a PayPal payment, and this is by design.